# Performing multiple inserts with Selected data

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to perform this sudo query:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (foreign_key, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES (
     (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met'), 'first meta key', 'first meta value'
)
VALUES (
     (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met'), 'second meta key', 'second meta value'
)
VALUES (
     (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met'), 'third meta key', 'third meta value'
)
```

Where the strings after the `SELECT` statements are the second and third arguments for the `INSERT`

I think I have the `INSERT SELECT` syntex basically right, but I'm not certain about the multiple `INSERTS`. I know I can do it like this with a normal `INSERT` statement, but I'm uncertain about the `SELECT` being inside the `VALUES` clause.

I'm working with a live database and although I have backed everything up, I want to keep direct experimentation to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use UNION:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (foreign_key, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT id, 'first meta key', 'first meta value' FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met'
UNION
SELECT id, 'second meta key', 'second meta value' FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met'
UNION
SELECT id, 'third meta key', 'third meta value' FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met'
```

Comment: I may have caused a misunderstanding here. I'm going to update the question - could you let me know if this will still work?

Comment: no, your query does not work (I'm using SQLServer 2005), the one with union works

Answer (score 1):

You need add comma between values.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (foreign_key, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES (
     (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met'), 'first meta key', 'first meta value'
),
(
     (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met'), 'second meta key', 'second meta value'
),
(
     (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met'), 'third meta key', 'third meta value'
)
```

And be sure every sub query return 1 row only.

Try this [Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da538/1/0).

Or use union as a normal way:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (foreign_key, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT id, 'first meta key' , 'first meta value'  FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met')
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'second meta key', 'second meta value' FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met')
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'third meta key' , 'third meta value'  FROM table2 WHERE condition = 'met')
```